# Is @"" and nil same?

Tags: objective-c, properties, nsstring

I have a

```
@property(retain) NSString* test;
```

It is synthezised in the implementation file.

In dealloc, is both of these are correct or not?

```
self.test = nil;
```

and

```
self.test = @"";
```

When I logged the retainCount of nil and @"", it gave the output as 0 and -1 respectively.

I'm just curious to know whether both yields same results.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might be of use to you. http://whentouseretaincount.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, never use retainCount for anything. It will lie to you. Secondly, the retain count is unsigned, so "-1" actually means "the highest possible retain count", which is a value that means retain and release do nothing on that object. Thirdly, calling any method on nil returns nil/0.

Now that that's cleared up: nil and @"" are not the same. nil is a pointer to address 0, and represents "no object". @"" is a perfectly valid NSString object that just happens to have no characters in it.

Comment: So it will not cause a leak self.test = @""; Right?

Comment: Also please tell is it necessary to do self.test = nil in dealloc? If we are not doing this, will this cause a memory leak?

Comment: Assigning or not assigning to a property, by itself, cannot cause a leak. What causes a leak is when the total count of retains and releases across the object's entire lifetime is not balanced. That said, technically, @"" can never leak (it's a special type of object); I find it simplest to ignore that and treat it like any other object.

Answer (score 2):

No you should always set the property to nil because it frees it of the memory while other way you are actually creating a string with zero characters .

For better understanding you can read [this] : http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-memory-management.html